# how to overcome android sqlite where clause problem?

Tags: android, database, android-sqlite, where-clause

I am trying to read data from students table where semester column is equal to an item which is selected from spinner. **listener is spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener.** the problem is it stops the activity when I select the spinner item. 
**It runs okay when I remove the WHERE CLAUSE.** but I have to use WHERE CLAUSE.
Please Help.

```
    public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> GetAllStudents(){
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> userList = new ArrayList<>();
        try{
            SQLiteDatabase db = MyDB.getInstance(this).getReadableDatabase();


        String query = "SELECT * FROM Students WHERE semester="+selected;
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query,null);
        if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                HashMap<String, String> user = new HashMap<>();
                user.put("name", cursor.getString(0));
                user.put("roll", cursor.getString(1));
                user.put("semester", cursor.getString(2));
                user.put("pass", cursor.getString(3));
                userList.add(user);
            }
        }

    }
    catch (Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Error "+selected, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    return  userList;
}
```

### EDIT

(code taken from comments to show where **selected** is comming from)

```
String selected; 
sp.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {    
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) { 
        selected=parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
        loadStudents();
    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) { 
    }
});

loadStudents();
```

Comment: Can you share your error log message? Also where is the `selected` coming from?

Comment: **String selected;**

 sp.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

               
selected=parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

                loadStudents();
            }

            
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });

        loadStudents();

Comment: selected is a string variable and I am using it to get the item selected from spinner

Comment: I can see that you are calling **loadStudents** even if the user selects nothing. Is that the expected behavior? I mean you have **loadStudents** inside **onItemSelected** and also outside it

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem , I just missed ' ' around the selected variable

This is the solution
String query = "SELECT * FROM Students WHERE semester='"+selected+"'";